# Как подстраивать QTextEdit под размеры текста

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Как можно подстроить размеры QTextEdit под размеры содержимого, те если текст выходит за его границы он не добавлял scroll, а менял свой размер чтобы полностью отобразить текст, и не переносил его при выходе за его границы.

Comment: widgetRect не используется. boundingRect как-то странно определяет размер текста. На мой взгляд задача не решена. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если "на коленках", то примерно так. Необходимо добавить слот для сигнала textChanged():

```
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    // !!!! Для обоих скроллбаров вашего QTextEdit необходимо установить Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff    
    QString s = ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); // нам понадобится сам текст
    QFontMetrics m(ui->textEdit->font()); // и метрики шрифта
    QRect widgetRect = ui->textEdit->rect(); // размер виджета        
    QRect textRect = m.boundingRect(QRect(0,0,0,0),Qt::TextWordWrap,s); // Найдем геометрические параметры текста (высота/ширина в пикселях) с учетом перевода строк
    int X = 10; // Честно говоря лень определять отступы. Если критично - вычисляйте сами
    ui->textEdit->resize(textRect.width()+X,textRect.height()+X); // Изменяем размер виджета

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Смею предположить, что стоит создать свой MyTextEdit, унаследовать его от QTextEdit и переопределить метод event(QEvent *e), а дальше ручками менять размеры QTextEdit