# QTextEdit в QScrollArea изменение размера виджета в соответствии с контентом

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, qtextedit

Ситуация следующая. Помещаю `QTextEdit` с текстом в виде обычной строки (из форматирования строки - только шрифт и его размер. никаких переносов на новую строку и табуляций) в `QScrollArea` динамически, по нажатию кнопки. 
`QTextEdit` прекрасно помещается в скролл-пространство, но размеры `QTextEdit` становятся непотребно большими, даже при наличии `Spacer`, принимая какие-то константные/коэффициентные значения, заложенные в `QTextEdit` разрабами.

Для простоты понимания иерархии окна - иллюстрация:

[image: иллюстрация]

Вопрос, как настроить `QTextEdit` таким образом, чтобы при наличии строки в одно слово `QTextEdit` уменьшался бы до размеров этого самого слова (рамки виджета не в счет). А при наличии строки в несколько предложений, `QTextEdit` бы растягивался до такой степени, чтобы вместить все предложение, **не** активируя тем самым свои внутренние скролл-бары. 
Расширение `QTextEdit` в ширину должно быть ограничено неким константным значением, чтобы при расширении `QTextEdit` **не** активировал бы горизонтальные скролл-бары у `QScrollArea` = при наличии большой строки, `QTextEdit` должен расширяться в высоту (активировать функцию переноса слов)

В результате ожидается примерно такая работа виджета

[image: пример]

Answer (score 0):

Как реализовать автоподгон размера QTextEdit под текст, я отвечал в свое время в [ответе на этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287713/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-qtextedit-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/1292614#1292614)

Вам остается только переписать с c++ на python и реализовать необходимый доп. функционал - разбиение на предложения и ограничение макс. размера

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


TEXT = """Вопрос, как настроить QTextEdit таким образом, \
чтобы при наличии строки в одно слово QTextEdit уменьшался \
бы до размеров этого самого слова (рамки виджета не в счет). \
А при наличии строки в несколько предложений, QTextEdit бы \
растягивался до такой степени, чтобы вместить все предложение, \
не активируя тем самым свои внутренние скролл-бары. Расширение \
QTextEdit в ширину должно быть ограничено неким константным значением, \
чтобы при расширении QTextEdit не активировал бы горизонтальные \
скролл-бары у QScrollArea = при наличии большой строки, \
QTextEdit должен расширяться в высоту (активировать функцию переноса слов)"""
TEXT2 = "Hello World"


class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.updateGeometry)
        self._height = 0
        palette = QPalette() 
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor('#FAFDD6'))
        self.setPalette(palette)                                
        
    def sizeHint(self):
        hint = super().sizeHint()
        if self.toPlainText():
            doc = self.document().clone()
            width = self.width() - self.frameWidth() * 2
            if self.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
                width -= self.verticalScrollBar().width()
            doc.setTextWidth(width)
            height = round(doc.size().height())
        else:
            height = self.fontMetrics().height()
            height += self.document().documentMargin() * 2
            
        height += self.frameWidth() * 2
        hint.setHeight(height)
        self._height = height
        return hint


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(0, 1, self)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        rowCount = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowCount)
        
        self.textEdit = TextEdit(self)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 0, self.textEdit)
        self.textEdit.setText(f'{TEXT}')
        self.textEdit.textChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        
        self.tableWidget.installEventFilter(self)   
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Короткий текст')
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=Qt.AlignBottom)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == event.Resize:
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents)
            self.tableWidget.setMaximumHeight(self.textEdit._height)
            QTimer.singleShot(
                1, 
                lambda: self.tableWidget.setMaximumHeight(self.textEdit._height))
            
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)     

    def text_changed(self):
        self.tableWidget.resizeRowToContents(0)
        self.tableWidget.setMaximumHeight(self.textEdit._height)
    
    def button_clicked(self, status):
        if status:
            self.textEdit.setText(f'{TEXT2}')
            self.pushButton.setText('Длинный текст')
        else:
            self.textEdit.setText(f'{TEXT}')
            self.pushButton.setText('Короткий текст')
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))   
    ex = MyApp()
    ex.resize(500, 400)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Otaku что не так?